# Conjugation in algebraic number theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field of deg $n$ over $\mathbb Q$, then given $\alpha \in$ $O_k$ its ring of integers, we can choose a $\mathbb Q$-basis $\omega_1, \omega_2, ...,\omega_n$ of $K$ s.t. $\alpha \omega_i=\sum a_{ij}\omega_j$ $\forall i$ where $a_{ij} \in \mathbb Q$.

> Let $\alpha^{(k)}$ be the $k$-th conjugate of $\alpha$, and $\omega_i^{(k)}$ be the $k$-th conjugate of $\omega_i$. Then $\alpha^{(k)}\omega_i^{(k)}=\sum a_{ij}\omega_j^{(k)} \forall i, k$.

Why is the above statement true? If I construct a monomorphism of $\mathbb Q(\omega_i)\rightarrow \mathbb Q(\omega_i^{(k)})$, then $\alpha \omega_i$ is sent to $\sum a_{ij}\omega_j^{(k)}$, but I'm not sure wether $\alpha$ is sent to $\alpha^{(k)}$ or not.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  I think all that is being said is that if $\sigma \in \text{Aut}(K/\mathbb{Q})$, then applying $\sigma$ to $\alpha \omega_i$ yields $\sigma(\alpha) \sigma(\omega_i) = \sum_j a_{ij} \sigma(\omega_j)$.  Each of $\sigma(\alpha), \sigma(\omega_i), \sigma(\omega_j)$ is *some* conjugate of $\alpha, \omega_i, \omega_j$, so we decide to number them all with the same index $k$.

Comment: @SpamiAm I think you are right, my mind is not clear when thinking this...

Comment: It’s not clear what the meaning of “the $k$-th conjugate” is, without saying something about a Galois group or a Galois set. For, the conjugates of a particular irrationality form an unordered and (conceptually) unlabeled set.

Comment: I think that $k$ is here simple as an index of the various embeddings $\sigma_k:K\to\Bbb{C}$, $k=1,2,\ldots,n$, $n=[K:\Bbb{Q}]$. And then for all elements $z\in K$ we denote $z^{(k)}:=\sigma_k(z)$. Unless we know that $K/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois this makes more sense than restricting us to automorphisms of $K$. As Lubin says, there is no canonical numbering of conjugates, but in a treatise such as this it is convenient to number the conjugates according to the embeddings (or automorphisms, if that is a better fit).